# Why is AMP-HTML changing around my code?

Tags: html, mobile, amp-html

I am converting an old site to AMP-HTML and have an issue. Here is my code..

```
<ul>
    <li><amp-img src="pic.png" layout="responsive" height="10" width="10"><h2>hello</h2></li>
</ul>
```

When I check it in the browser it pushes the image down and puts the h2 on top of the image.

Comment: Please show the URL. Several things might be happening here but any suggestion would just be a WAG.

Answer (score 2):

This is beacuse your `<amp-img>` tag is not closed. close the tag as below.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <amp-img src="pic.png" layout="responsive" height="10" width="10">
    </amp-img>
    <h2>hello</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should work as I haven't encountered any issue with `<amp-img>` tag as of now.